# how to use google translate paid api in android

Tags: java, android, google-translate

H, i want to use google paid translate api, i have enable billing and activate that api from google console service

[image]

i have also generated the android key

[image]

but every time i am getting error like below screen

**"Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.**

[image]

Comment: Did you call `setDeveloperKey`?  Show us some code or something.

Comment: can u help me? i have not set any developer key! from where can i found it?

Comment: Check this example for Google Picker https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/